# Control.Monad.Writer example

Tags: haskell, monads

Looking at some `Writer` monad examples, in the one from *Learn You a Haskell* I don't see where the use of `*` multiplication operator in the last line expression is overloaded to work with the with the `Writer` objects produced by the `logNumber` functions:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer  

logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int  
logNumber x = Writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])  

multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int  
multWithLog = do  
    a <- logNumber 3  
    b <- logNumber 5  
    return (a*b)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be some misunderstanding here. In your example code:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer  

logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int  
logNumber x = Writer (x, ["Got number: " ++ show x])  

multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int  
multWithLog = do  
    a <- logNumber 3  
    b <- logNumber 5  
    return (a*b)
```

the values `a` and `b` are *not* `Writer` values. Their type is simply `Int`, and of course you can multiply 2 `Int`s. Therefore `a*b` is an `Int` too - note the use of `return` on it in the last line, which is needed here precisely in order to "lift" the "ordinary value" `a*b` of type `Int` to a "monadic value" of type `Writer [String] Int`.

`logNumber 3` is certainly a monadic value (of type `Writer [String] Int`), but the `<-` syntactic sugar of `do` notation "extracts" the underlying value out of it, and gives it a name - here `a`. More precisely, the `do` block above desugars to:

```
multWithLog = logNumber 3 >>= \a -> logNumber 5 >>= \b -> return (a*b)
```

where the lambda expressions have type `Int -> Writer [String] Int` (the arguments `a` and `b` being the `Int`s in question), which due to the type of `>>=` produces an expression of type `Writer [String] Int` overall.

Comment: Ah; yes - I was overlooking the deconstruction of the writer tuple in the >>= operator definition. The magic of hidden monadic computations. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, indeed - but note that none of my above argument relies on the fact that `Writer` happens to extract a value from a tuple in the `>>=` definition. We need know nothing about `Writer` at all, other than that `Writer [String]` is a monad, and everything I said in my answer would still be true, and mean that `a` and `b` in the code example have type `Int`.

Comment: Indeed - interesting.  But it does seem that the monad instance for Writer is needed to propagate the associated string(s).

Comment: yes indeed, what `Writer [String]` does as its "side effect" is append a string to a growing collection. (And it works the same way for any monoid `m` in place of `[String]`.)